# Removing duplicate attribute in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I understand this is one such common question posted many times, but unfortunately I am unable to find an exact solution with any of the proposed approaches:

Here's how my XML looks like:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <table>
    <attr ......>
       <type t="enumone">
       <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr>

    <attr>
        <type t="int">
        <range min="1" max="255"/>
         </type>
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr>

    <attr>
        <type t="string">
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr> 
    <attr ......>
       <type t="enumtwo">
       <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr>

    <attr>
        <type t="float">
        <range min="1.0" max="25.5"/>
         </type>
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr>

    <attr>
        <type t="int">
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr> 


    <attr>
        <type t="enumone">
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr> 
    <attr>
        <type t="enumthree">
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr> 
    <attr>
        <type t="enumone">
         <info>
        <name .....>
       </info>
    </attr> 
    </parent>
 </root>
```

The intention is to retrieve one occurrence of attribute "@t" from "type" element by using XSLT:

```
Using for-each-group:
<xsl-template match="/root/parent">
  <xsl:for-each select="table">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//type" group-by="@t">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group( )[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each>
<xsl-template>
```

But I got no output! Something flawed I believe.

Using distinct-values():

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(type/@t)">
<xsl:sort/>
<xsl:value-of select="."/> <xsl:call-template name="newline"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Still no desired output.

The expected output is:

```
enumone
int
string
enumtwo
float
enumthree
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Well the input sample is not well-formed XML but if you really only want the distinct `t` attribute values of all `type` elements then doing

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//type/@t)" separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>
```

suffices with XSLT 2.0.

If you additionally want to sort the distinct values then doing

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of separator="&#10;">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values(//type/@t)">
       <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>
```

To give a complete example, with the input being

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <type t="int"/>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <type t="enum"/>
  </bar>
  <foobar>
     <foo>
        <type t="enum">
           <x/>
        </type>
     </foo>
   </foobar>
   <foo>
      <type t="string"/>
   </foo>
</root>
```

the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of separator="&#10;">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values(//type/@t)">
       <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
enum
int
string
```

Comment: Martin, wonderful!!, this was bang on target!! I got the desired output, distinct-values(//type/@t) did the trick, if possible please shed some light on "separator" used. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: `distinct-values(//type/@t)` gives us a sequence of string values and to output the values of that sequence separated by line feeds we use `<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//type/@t)" separator="&#10;"/>`. The default separator is a space I think, as your requested output has each item on a line of its own I used `separator="&#10;"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just modify your code to this**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//type" group-by="@t">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group( )[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

**The complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//type" group-by="@t">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group( )[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on a well-formed XML document**:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <type t="int"/>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <type t="enum"/>
  </bar>
  <foobar>
     <foo>
        <type t="enum">
           <x/>
        </type>
     </foo>
   </foobar>
   <foo>
      <type t="string"/>
   </foo>
</root>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
<type t="int"/>
<type t="enum"/>
<type t="string"/>
```